# How to remove log4j warnings in selenium test?

Tags: java, selenium

in my selenium test i added log4j jars when i was adding other jars.
since that time when i run my test i see this:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f) on port 3737
Only local connections are allowed.

    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

How can i remove the warning.
Thank you

Comment: Do you want logging, and just want to get rid of the configuration error?  (i.e. removing log4j from the java build path would turn off logging)

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, you have not only added the jars but also have referenced/used some of the **`Classes`** and **`Methods`** from these `JARs` in one of the `Module`/`Program`/`Script`.

Now, to remove the `log4j Warnings` you have to remove the **`Log4j`** `JARs` from the list of `External JAR` list within `Java Build Path`.